# Get specific number in string after divided character

Tags: c#

If I have a formular like "(10 / 0) + (29 / 0.0) + (10 / 0.1)" as String, I want throw a **devide by zero** exception. For that case, I have to parse the String and check all numbers in past of the divide character.

How can I solve that with a function?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sry, forgot that =(

Answer (score 0):

As a starting suggestion, you could use the ScriptEngine class in order to evaluate it as a JS expression:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
Object result = engine.eval("(10 / 0) + (29 / 0.0) + (10 / 0.1)");
```

And then raise the appropriate Exception.

Answer (score 0):

This will throw an DivideByZero exception, otherwise will return you the result.

```
try
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    var result = dt.Compute("(10 / 0) + (29 / 0.0) + (10 / 0.1)", "");
    //Work with further result here
}
catch(System.DivideByZeroException e)
{
    //Your exception here    
}
```